# Is there a source for historical LTC trades available?

Tags: litecoin, historical-trade-data

From bitcoincharts.com can download historical trade histories for BTC on various exchanges vs various currencies.

Where can I find something comparable for LTC?  I want to get historical trades for LTC vs USD & CNY.  1 year or more would be ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These files contain every LTC trade from day 1 through about 2:20pm UTC on 31-3-2013.

LTCBTC @ BTCe Oct 2011 through March 2013
http://www.mediafire.com/view/?5cwjmviou15k32h

LTCUSD @ BTCe Oct 2011 through March 2013
http://www.mediafire.com/view/?cn5qxi44j6egrad

also Kraken LTCEUR charts are here:
http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/

I'm looking for 2013 and 2014 BTCe LTCUSD and LTCBTC.

please help

Comment: Well, how did you obtain these in the first place?

Comment: These are not my files.  I obtained them through hours of google searching reading forum threads.  I have the links bookmarked tbh I don't remember which forum thread I found them in.

Comment: The api.bitcoincharts.com data is totally legit; that's a rock solid source.  The old LTC data I've opened and plotted... it seems clean.

Comment: I just open sourced the process by which to plot the old LTC data at Tradewave.net in python. It includes numpy float arrays of HLOC, Volume, and TAlib Indicators. https://discuss.tradewave.net/t/importing-csv-price-data-to-backtest-engine-via-google-sheets/515

Comment: Where can get updated historial intraday data for LTC, ETH or other important coins?