# Looking for raw historical LTC data

Tags: litecoin, historical-trade-data

Something comparable -- though not necessarily as comprehensive -- to the datasets found here: http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/

These links are all dead:
[Is there a source for historical LTC trades available?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35706/is-there-a-source-for-historical-ltc-trades-available/36348)

This site apparently had full trade data history: http://ltc.block-explorer.com/charts

...But that's dead as well.

help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but better late than never.

No guarantee given for accuracy. 
From day one to January 8 2016
For the first 262 days the average trading price is used as no closing price available.

Bitcoin price mainly from Bitstamp, Litecoin from BTCe so LTC-BTC is a bit different for BTCe price

No trade first couple of days ltc-dollar price established from ltc-btc and bitcoin dollar
The lowest closing price was on May 29 2012 at $0.0023.
The lowest recorded deal January 23 2012 at  1:36:42   $ 0.001302   4.20697  Litecoins changed hands at that price (did have all volume too, but gone. was just a spreadsheet, but link to it dead too)
Three days did not have any trades at all: 17.March 2012, 6.May 2012, 17.May 2012

[LTC-USD](https://pastebin.com/raw/k2vG2XMf)

[LTC-BTC](https://pastebin.com/raw/uBpjNBvc)

Comment: Pastebin contents will end up being a dead link just like the rest, so I'm afraid this is not a good case of "better late than never". Also, @Dave is asking for datasets, not vague prices inlined in the response.

Comment: What about intraday data?